# What is the best way to access next/previous inputs nested within ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am adding `keyup` bindings to inputs that are nested within ng-repeats in order to smoothly go from next to previous input similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14777923/2013981). The difference being that the solution there was for inputs that were directly adjacent siblings.

Here's a prototype of my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="student in students" >
  <div class="input-append">
    <input class="span3" type="text" ng-model="student.name"
       ng-required="student.name.split(' ').length>1" focus-others index="{{ $index }}" focus="{{ focus.value }}"/>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="deleteInput($index)">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I currently have two solutions that both work.

---

**First Solution** - traverses the dom looking for inputs, matches the input that's focused, then on `keyup` focuses the next input:

```
app.directive('focusOthers', function($timeout){
  return function(scope, element){
    var inputs;
    $timeout(function(){
        inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    },0)
    element.bind('keyup', function(e){
        var current = document.activeElement;      
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            event.preventDefault();
            var i = 0;
            while( i<inputs.length){
                if (inputs[i]==current){                        
                    var nextInput = inputs[i+1];
                    nextInput.focus();
                    i=inputs.length;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    })
}
});
```

[Here's a working plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/mDONK5hg6pk4Ba3MllOY?p=preview)

---

**Second Solution** - this is a more "angular" solution, in that the directive processes information within the element's attributes to determine which element gets the focus.

```
app.directive('focusOthers', function(){
return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        // scope.index = attrs.index - wouldn't it be nice if this worked?
        attrs.$observe('index', function(val){
            scope.index = parseInt(val);
        });
        attrs.$observe('focus', function(val){
            if(scope.focus.value == scope.index){
                element[0].focus();
            }
        });

        element.bind('keyup', function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==13){
                scope.focus.value = scope.index + 1;
                scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

[Here's the plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/GlKuQKtDQJLEbiTkrvqr?p=preview) for this method.

**Possible cons with each:**

The first method is pure dom traversal.  I don't necessarily have a problem with that, but everytime you traverse the dom and a `$timeout` is used to wait for rendering, someone will shout "That's not what angular was designed for."

--
The second method is more "angular" I guess, but the directive registers `$observe` on the attributes, and with the possibility of 400+ inputs on the page, I don't know if this will affect performance.

**So my question** is, is there a better way to gain access to these nested inputs that will both appease the angular gods AND go easy on the browser?  Or is one of my methods a better way to go? Or should I just give up and do this all in Python/Jinja2 ;) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a more browser/user satisfying approach would be to use the tabindex attribute. You can spit out this attribute on each input element and use the $index value to get the iteration number that ng-repeat is on. A lot of browsers and mobile devices hook into this attribute to provide navigation through forms and lists (e.g. the forward/back arrows in iOS when focused on a form input)

Another solution is use a directive each element

```
<input focus-this="{{$index}}"></input>
```

Then

```
directives.directive('focusThis', function(){
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$watch('focusedIndex', function(newVal, oldVal){
                if (newVal == attrs['focus-this']){
                    element.focus();
                }
                else {
                    element.blur();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You should be able to change focusedIndex with keydown events to go previous/next or even to jump to specific indexes if you'd like.

*Warning: Untested code. Just a concept. May need tweaks.*

Comment: I was being a bit lazy in my examples, but the production version will have controls for left/right/up/down arrows.  This is mainly a desktop app.  Also, each repeated element may contain other input types.  I just want to move between the text boxes.  Can I programatically access that attribute?

Comment: I see.  IOW, using the second method, I just replace my `index` attr with `tabindex`. I had not thought of that :)/  Do you think hundreds of $observes will have any adverse effect?  If you could update your answer accordingly I'll check it.

Comment: According to the angular FAQ: "Just for an illustration we typically build snappy apps with hundreds or thousands of active bindings." As always, your results may vary... But this is pretty confidence inspiring :-)